# NextJS: hash id anchor does not working in some moments

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js

I was trying to move user to a certain position (which a HTMLElement with a given id is) when user click a button. So far I have tried using hashtag directly and using hash tag and add a listener listen to the router change in useEffect, and send user to the element if hashtag is detected and that element is not in the view port. They are not working at most of the time. I added a `while` loop to keep triggering the function, which results bringing user to the element after 20+ calls in 7-8 seconds. That is just annoying.

Does anyone successfully make the hashtag works? How can that be done?

What I have tried so far:
hashtag link: failed
hashtag link with a slash before the hashtag: failed, can't see a difference
function moving user to the location: failed, but the function itself is successfully triggered

What I am observing at the moment:

1. User is not moved at all
2. User is moved, but the process suddenly stops before user actually reach that element. I used smooth behavior as my global css, so this effect is really strange to me.
3. Keep checking if user is not reaching that position, and send them to it if checked. Not working as expected. It does check and send user and send again if another check still fails, but the process is too long (7-8 seconds, or longer) and if user scroll in the process they will still be dragged to the element if they haven't reach it.

Related code:

```js
  function isInViewport(el: HTMLElement) {
    const rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    return (
        rect.top >= 0 &&
        rect.left >= 0 &&
        rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
        rect.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
      );
  }
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const path = router.asPath;
    if (path && path.includes('/#')) {
      const sectionName = path.replace('/#', '');
      const ele = document.getElementById(sectionName);
      if (ele) {
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
          if (!isInViewport(ele)) {
            console.log('triggered');
            setTimeout(() => {
              ele.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" })
            }, 2000)
          }
          else {
            clearInterval(interval);
          }
        }, 2000);
      }
    }
  }, [router.asPath]);
```

Comment: Any reason why you're handling the scrolling logic yourself? Have you tried simply using a link, e.g. `<Link href="/#some-hash-id"><a>Go to anchor</a></Link>`?

Comment: @juliomalves Yes tried, the scrolling could still stuck on somewhere in the middle sometimes.